# Redirect and keep Referral Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have a page which I redirect from it to another page (let's call it "middle page") with parameters in the query string. and I want to redirect from the middle page to some other page in another domain without losing the referral url (the query string of the middle page). my project is MVC C#.

I've tried:
- redirecting in the server side -> didn't work since the query string of the middle page didn't have a chance to change in the client side.
- redirecting in the client side through java script: location.replace/ location.href -> didn't keep the referral url.
- redirecting in the client side with Meta tag refresh -> didn't work.

I did see that if i place a link () in the middle page, clicking it would keep the referral url. so my last resolution was placing a javascript that automatically clicks on the link on document load-> it didn't work as well.

anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit a form using javascript: **(Edited version)**

So, we have a file "first.html" which calls "middle.html" with parameters:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.location.href="middle.html?a=1&b=2";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now "middle.html" makes form-submit to another domain:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var myForm = document.createElement("form");
            myForm.method = "GET";

            myForm.action = "http://google.com";

            document.body.appendChild(myForm);
            myForm.submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I checked it in FF with Firebug where under GET-request i can see HttpHeader "Referer" which equals to "middle.html?a=1&b=2"

Comment: thanx but it the referrer url still returns the first page url and not the middle one

Comment: @Atlanta please see edited version. Form submition should be from middle page

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using a timeout before I auto-click my link.
however I don't like this solution. does anyone have a better solution?